# Como borrar o limpiar una tablewidget en Pyqt5 o Pyqt

Tags: pyqt5

Hola Gente como se puede borrar o limpiar una `tablewidget` en `Pyqt5` o `Pyqt`?

```
self.obj_form_cliente ---> esto es el formulario 
tw_garantes_lista  ---- > esto es como se llama el control "nombre de del control tipo tablewidget"

while (self.obj_form_cliente.tw_garantes_lista.rowCount() > 0)
        self.obj_form_cliente.tw_garantes_lista.removeRow(0)
```

bueno espero que les sirva  :)

Answer (score 1):

Para limpiar el `QTableWidget` puedes utilizar el método `clear()` para limpiar todo el *widget*, en otras palabras, lo reiniciaríamos completamente. Usando el método `clearContents()` limpiamos solo el contenido.